# Замена класса

Tags: javascript

Имеиться код по замены класса при смены разрешения экрана, но сама замена не происходит, прошу помочь разобраться что не так.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var wi = $(window).width();

        if (wi >= 1300){
            $('.comment-text-block').replaceWith($('.comment-text-blocks'));
            }
    });            
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно изменить только класс, то так:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var wi = $(window).width();

        if (wi >= 1300){
            var $block = $('.comment-text-block');
            $block.addClass('comment-text-blocks').removeClass('comment-text-block');
        }
    });            
});
```

Если содержимое, то убедитесь, что $('.comment-text-blocks') существует и у него есть содержимое...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi < 600 && $('.comment-text-block').length > 0){
        $('.comment-text-block').replaceWith($('.comment-text-blocks'));
    }
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/xbzyd/

Я так понял, у вас при изменении размера окна происходит неоднократное выполнение скрипта, из-за этого происходит неоднократная замена блоков. А т.к. блока `.comment-text-block` нет, но блок `.comment-text-blocks` уже вырезан, то все блоки удаляются.